# Why do I need to type-cast an object when sending it an "isKindOf:" message?

Tags: objective-c, types, warnings, casting

If I'm trying to find out if an object is a type of a certain class (or any of that class's descendants), it seems that I should use "isKindOf:"

```
if ([foo isKindOfClass:[bar class]]) {...}
```

But the compiler gives me a warning "invalid receiver type 'void *'".

This goes away if I cast "foo" to NSObject...or any other class!  No matter what class I cast the object to, the code still works.  That is, even if I do:

```
if ([(NSString *)foo isKindOfClass:[bar class]]) {...}
```

the "isKindOfClass" method still returns TRUE if and only if "foo" is of type "bar".

Am I missing something here?  Shouldn't casting "foo" to another type make the logic fail?  And why do I need to cast "foo" at all, since the whole point is that I'm trying to figure out what type of object it is?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you've declared foo as:

```
void* foo;
```

void* is not an Objective-C type, so you can't send it messages like `isKindOfClass`.

Declare foo like this instead:

```
id foo;
```